# Отображение курсора в поле телефона

Tags: javascript, html, css, mask

Использую обычный плагин jquery.maskedinput.js для задания поле с телефоном. Можно ли сделать, чтобы при клике на любое место в инпуте курсор перескакивал в начало ввода номера, а то если кликнуть в конце инпута, курсор там и останется

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Ваш телефон" id="phone5">
<script>
    $("#phone5").mask("+375 (99) 999-99-99");
</script>
```

Comment: Так а если телефон полностью вбит и пользователь кликнув в поле попадает курсором в начало, тогда ему нужно будет удалить все символы клавишей Delete и вписать всё по новой, как-то через *опу будет всё работать, вам не кажется? Да и вообще, пользователю при вводе данных привычней удалять Backspace'ом чем Delet'ом

Comment: При вводе телефона телефон не вбит, т.е. есть только код страны и все, остальные символы, которые нужно вбить просто нижним подчеркиванием обозначены

Comment: Плагин работает таким образом, что, если пользователь не до конца ввел телефон и снял фокус с поля, оно автоматически очистится соответственно новый клик поставит курсор в начало, если он ввел полностью телефон и в следующий раз кликнул на указанные телефон идет выделение всего поля при вводе символа всё итак удалится и начнет ввод с 1го символа, возможно вы не корректно подключили плагин и/или работаете с ним, читайте документацию и делай по [примерам](https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/blob/master/demo/index.html).

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо большое

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может немного не в тему вопроса, лишним точно не будет. Если у вас только маска для телефона, не забивайте сайт лишними библиотеками. Используйте данный скрипт:

```js
var phoneInput = document.querySelector("#phone-mask");
phoneInput.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  "ArrowLeft" != e.key && "ArrowRight" != e.key && "Backspace" != e.key && "Tab" != e.key && e.preventDefault();
  var t = "+375 (111) 111-11-11";
  if (/[0-9\+\ \-\(\)]/.test(e.key)) {
    var a = this.value,
      n = a.length;
    if (/[0-9]/.test(e.key))
      if ("1" == t[n]) this.value = a + e.key;
      else
        for (var r = n; r < t.length; r++) {
          if ("1" == t[r]) {
            this.value = a + e.key;
            break
          }
          a += t[r]
        }
  }
});
```

```html
<input placeholder="+375 (XXX) XXX-XX-XX" id="phone-mask" type="text">
```

С курсором проблем конечно же не будет.

Comment: Брррррррр... Как тут надо догадаться, что вводить надо цифру, а не плюс? И как догадаться, что не код? Ну и всё остальное даже проверять не хочется.